# Does the preimage of a critical value for a function contain a submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Suppose that $(M,g)$ is a compact Riemannian manifold and $f:M\to [a,b]$ a smooth function such that $\|\nabla f\|$ is constant along each level set.

Also we know that $a$ and $b$ are the only critical values and each of the level sets $f^{-1}(a)$ and $f^{-1}(b)$ has dimension $k<n-1$, where $n=\dim M$. Moreover we know that for every $c,d\in [a,b]$, $d(p,f^{-1}(d))=d(f^{-1}(c), q)= d(f^{-1}(c), f^{-1}(d))$, $\forall\ p \in f^{-1}(c)$ and $q \in f^{-1}(q)$.

Here $\nabla f$ is the gradient of $f$, that is defined as $df_p(v)=g(\nabla f, v)$, $\forall v \in T_pM$.

**Can one guarantee that there exists an embedded submanifolds $L$ of $M$ of dimension $k$ which is contained in $f^{-1}(b)$?** and also the same result for $f^{-1}(a)$?

P.S. By the dimension of $f^{-1}(b)$ we mean the dimension of it is it is a submanifold.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that each of the level sets has dimension $k$? It sounds like you are saying that each one of these level sets is a $k$-dimensional submanifold.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Something like if they are smooth submanifolds, they are of dimension k. However we do not know if they are or not! Something like a non smooth manifold of dimension k!